# Use the delete key to decline meeting in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When I delete a meeting request in Outook for Windows, using the delete key or icon, the meeting is still added to my calendar.

Is there a setting that will decline the meeting, without sending a response, just by pressing the delete key or icon?

Comment: Is this issue resolved now? If so, would you mind marking the helpful post as an answer? Which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a setting that will decline the meeting, without sending a
> response, just by pressing the delete key or icon?

No.

Meeting requests are meant to be dealt with and really are a "people" thing, and not an "Outlook" thing.

If you wish to decline the meeting, click on Decline and then Send / Receive to ensure the meeting organizer knows you are not going to be attending.

Once the meeting is complete, you can delete it like any Outlook item including Delete Key.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, whether you are a meeting organizer or a meeting participant, you can directly delete expired meetings on the calendar by pressing the "delete" key without sending a response.

However, for meetings that do not occur, you need to process them manually. If you are a **meeting participant**, after you select a conference and press the "delete" button, a pop-up window will appear to prompt you whether you need to send a response. Just click "no" and the meeting will disappear directly in your calendar.

[image]

If you are the **meeting organizer**, I'm afraid that you can't directly delete the meeting just by pressing the delete key or icon. You have to send a cancellation notice to the meeting participants. It's by design.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I created a rule that moves offending meeting requests directly to the `Junk` mail folder.  This prevents them from being added to my calendar, while still allowing me to review them for relevancy.